# EF4 CTP5 - Audit columns CreatedOn

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Just beeen using EF4 CTP code first and was wondering how to enable audit fields such as CreatedOn (datetime) will this get populated when I save an item or do I have to do some mapping?

Thanks in advance

DotnetShadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate them in your code or if you want EF to generate DB for you, you need a mapping (at least present them in your POCO class). If you have existing database and this column will never be presented in your application you don't need mapping. Instead you can set default value of that column (in MS SQL you will use GetDate() as default value).

Comment: So if my POCO object has a property
DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } 

That is enough for EF Code first to use, or you saying I have to do extra mapping?

Comment: With basic mapping it should be enough to define the property in your class and define DbSet for that class in your derived DbContext.